# Cannot borrow variable when borrower scope ends

Tags: rust

I can't understand why a mutable borrowed variable is still borrowed after the scope of the borrower ends. It looks like it is related to trait usage, but I don't see why:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = 10;
    test::<FooS>(&mut a);
    println!("out {:?}", a)
}

trait Foo<'a> {
    fn new(data: &'a mut u32) -> Self;
    fn apply(&mut self);
}

struct FooS<'a> {
    data: &'a mut u32,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> for FooS<'a> {
    fn new(data: &'a mut u32) -> Self {
        FooS { data: data }
    }

    fn apply(&mut self) {
        *self.data += 10;
    }
}

fn test<'a, F>(data: &'a mut u32)
    where F: Foo<'a>
{
    {
        // let mut foo = FooS {data: data}; // This works fine
        let mut foo: F = Foo::new(data);
        foo.apply();
    } // foo scope ends here
    println!("{:?}", data); // error
} // but borrowed till here
```

[try online](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2efab9502dcf3d5fd5ffe74972aa31a3&version=stable&backtrace=0)

```
error: cannot borrow `data` as immutable because `*data` is also borrowed as mutable [--explain E0502]
   --> <anon>:34:22
31  |>         let mut foo: F = Foo::new(data);
    |>                                   ---- mutable borrow occurs here
...
34  |>     println!("{:?}", data); // error
    |>                      ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
35  |> } // but borrowed till here
    |> - mutable borrow ends here
```

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dabe17d66a14e72c2ca67e064ca26601&version=nightly&backtrace=0 works. so...

Comment: Nevertheless, this seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `test` function requires that type `F` implements `Foo<'a>`. The `'a` there is a lifetime parameter that's passed to the function. Lifetime parameters always represent lifetimes that live longer than the function call – because there is just no way a caller could supply a reference with a shorter lifetime; how could you pass a reference to a local variable from *another function*? –, and for the purposes of borrow checking (which is local to a function), the compiler considers that the borrow covers the whole function call.

Therefore, when you create an instance of `F` from the call to `Foo::new`, you create an object that borrows something with lifetime `'a`, a lifetime that covers the whole function call.

It's important to understand that when you call `test::<FooS>`, the compiler actually fills in a lifetime parameter for `FooS<'a>`, so you end up calling `test::<FooS<'a>>`, where `'a` is the region that covers the statement that contains the function call (because `&mut a` is a temporary expression). Therefore, the compiler thinks that the `FooS` that would be constructed in `test` would borrow something until the end of the statement with the call to `test`!

Let's contrast this with the nongeneric version:

```
let mut foo = FooS {data: data};
```

In this version, the compiler chooses a concrete lifetime for `FooS<'a>` in `test`, rather than in `main`, so it will choose the block suffix extending from the end of the `let` statement to the end of the block, which means that the next borrow of `data` doesn't overlap and there's no conflict.

What you really want is that `F` implement `Foo<'x>` for some lifetime `'x` that is shorter than `'a`, and most importantly, that lifetime must be a region within the function, not an enclosing one like `'a` is.

Rust's current solution to this problem is higher-ranked trait bounds. It looks like this:

```
fn test<'a, F>(data: &'a mut u32)
    where F: for<'x> Foo<'x>
{
    {
        let mut foo: F = Foo::new(data);
        foo.apply();
    }
    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

In words, it means *the type `F` must implement `Foo<'x>` for every possible `'x`*.

While this version of `test` compiles on its own, we cannot actually supply a type that fulfills this constraint, because for every possible lifetime `'a`, there is a distinct type `FooS<'a>` that only implements `Foo<'a>`. If `FooS` had no lifetime parameter and the impl of `Foo` for `FooS` looked like this:

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> for FooS {
```

then it would be fine, since there is a single type `FooS` that implements `Foo<'a>` for every possible lifetime `'a`.

Of course, you can't remove the lifetime parameter on `FooS`, as it contains a borrowed pointer. The proper solution for this problem is a feature that Rust doesn't have yet: the ability to pass a type constructor (rather than a fully constructed type) as a generic parameter to a function. With this capability, we could call `test` with `FooS`, a type constructor that needs a lifetime parameter to produce a concrete type, without specifying the concrete lifetime at the call site, and the caller would be able to supply its own lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Still one unclear moment for me. As you said _"Lifetime parameters always represent lifetimes that live longer than the function call, and for the purposes of borrow checking (which is local to a function), the compiler considers that the borrow covers the whole function call."_. Why compiler compiler consider this? We have lifetime that lives longer then function scope. But how it related to that borrow covers the whole function call? Is it details of implementation or part of specification?

Comment: There is no proper "specification" of Rust yet, so the implementation is the closest thing to a spec you'll get. For your other question, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just condensing some points made by @FrancisGagné for easier reference:

- First, we need to solve for `'a`.
- Since all inputs to the function must live at least as long as the function lifetime.
- Therefore `'a` will live as long as the function lifetime.
- Then, since `foo` has the type `Foo<'a>`, it is inferred that `foo` will mutably borrow `data` until then end of the function.
- Therefore the lifetimes of the immutable and mutable references overlap, triggering the compilation error.